How to Enforce Type Dependencies Between Object Properties in TypeScript Function Parameters?
I am attempting to create a function that takes a parameter P, which is an object with the following limitations:

P may have a property of type Transformers which is defined as { [key in keyof T]?: (value: unknown) => unknown }
P may have a property of type Comparers which is defined as { [key in keyof T]?: (obj: T, key: keyof T, value: T[key]) => boolean }
If P has both Transformers and Comparers, for keys that appear in both, the value of that key in Comparers should be based on the return value of the matching Transformer.

Example:
type T1 = { a: string; b: number; c: Date }
type Transformers<T> = { [key in keyof T]?: (value: unknown) => unknown };
type Comparers<T> = { [key in keyof T]?: (obj: T, key: keyof T, value: T[key]) => boolean };
declare function MyFunc<T>(P: {
  transformers: Transformers<T>,
  comparers: Comparers<T>
}
MyFunc<T1>({
  transformers: {
    c: (value: number) => {
      const from = new Date();
      const to = new Date();
      from.setMinutes(from.getMinutes() - value);
      return { from, to };
    }
  },
  comparers: {
    a: (obj: T, value: string) => obj.a.startsWith(value),
    c: (obj: T, value: { from: Date, to: Date }) => obj.c > value.from && obj[key] < value.to,
  }
})

This, of course, gives a typescript error on line 19 because the value for c in comparers does not match the type of T.c.
My closest attempt to create a type for this so far:


type Transformer = (...args: unknown[]) => unknown;
type Transformers<T> = { [key in keyof T]?: Transformer };
type t1 = { a: number; b: string; c: Date };

type Comparers<T, TR = undefined> = {
  [key in keyof T]?: (
    obj: T,
    value: key extends keyof TR
      ? TR[key] extends Transformer
        ? ReturnType<TR[key]>
        : T[key]
      : T[key]
  ) => boolean;
};

declare function Settings<T, TR extends Transformers<T>>(settings: {
  transformers?: TR;
  comparers: Comparers<T, TR>;
}): unknown;

const transformers = {
  b: (value: unknown) => Number(value),
  c: (value: unknown) => {
    const from = new Date();
    const to = new Date();
    from.setMinutes(from.getMinutes() - Number(value));
    return { from, to };
  },
};
Settings<t1, typeof transformers>({
  transformers,
  comparers: {
    a: (obj: t1, value: number) => {
      const val = obj.a;
      return val == value;
    },
    b: (obj: t1, value: number) => {
      const val = obj.b;
      return val.length >= value;
    },
    c: (obj: t1, value: { from: Date; to: Date }) => {
      const val = obj.c;
      return val > value.from && val < value.to;
    },
  },
});



This works, but it requires that I create an object for Transformers and pass its type to the function.
Is there a way to do the checks that I am going for within the function's parameter type, with only one generic T being required, and the rest being inferred from the parameter's properties?

No, this is not possible. You need to work around it, such as via currying, as shown in this playground link. See linked q/a above for more info
